# How can I make a chart with visual c# express 2008?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, visual-c#-express-2010

I've been searching the web for a tutorial in creating a line graph in c# but all i can find is for the visual c# 2010 express. i tried to download and convert my files from version 2008 to 2010. when i run my program in version 2010 no error appeared but a line of text in my class is highlighted and the execution just stopped. the highlighted text is the classes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
namespace spms.classes
{
public class clsOpenCon
{
    public static string connectionAddress = "uid=root; database=thesisdb;";
    public static MySqlConnection CN = new MySqlConnection(classes.clsOpenCon.connectionAddress);
    public MySqlCommand Com = new MySqlCommand();
    public MySqlDataReader reader;

    public void nonQuery(string cmdText)
    {
        Com.Connection = CN;
        CN.Open();
        Com.CommandText = cmdText;
        Com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Com.Dispose();
        CN.Close();
    }   

    public void OPEN(string cmdtext)
    {
        Com.Connection = classes.clsOpenCon.CN;
        classes.clsOpenCon.CN.Open();
        Com.CommandText = cmdtext;
        reader = Com.ExecuteReader();
    }

    public void CLOSE()
    {
        reader.Close();
        Com.Dispose();
        classes.clsOpenCon.CN.Close();
    }
    public DataTable ExecuteQuery(string cmdtext)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        var refDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(new MySqlCommand(cmdtext, CN));
        refDataAdapter.Fill(table);
        return table;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What sort of project Winforms? WPF? ASP.NET? the traditional way is to use reporting services but I'm loathed to recommend that to anyone... there are quite a few good js graph libraries

Comment: Not sure what your issue was or which line you are referring to, but there is a nice Chart control in the Data tab of the Toolbox in VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you might consider upgrading...  I'm using VCS 2010.

I know in the 2010 version there are tools for graphing.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you do not need any updates.

Go to the following Microsoft link and download the Chart control:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422

After installing it, close Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition if it is already open and then open it.

Choose your project.

Right click in the Toolbox and select Choose Items:

Select these two items from the .NET Framework Components tab:
Chart System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting
Chart System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualzation.Charting